# Как правильно использовать get и set в C#

Tags: c#, инкапсуляция

Всем привет. Использую get и set таким способом:

```
public struct Hero
{
    private float health;

    public float Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set { health = value; }
    }
}
```

Поле health темнеет и есть подсказка "Использовать свойство auto" - что это такое?

Стоит ли писать так:

```
public float health {get; set;}
```

Тогда переменная становится публичной и нарушается признак инкапсуляции?

Comment: Не становится, Ваш второй кусок полностью эквивалентен первому, за исключение того, что у Вас нет контроля над полем `health`.

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант идентичен первому, за исключением того, что более развернуто (как в первом варианте) за вас сделает компилятор. Это называется **Автоматически реализуемые свойства**. 
Более подробно можете [почитать в официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).